# How can I use export to excel and get the full file path?

Tags: sharepoint-server, export-to-excel

In the past when I used export to excel the full path was shown as
"../../../../../../../../Departments/EIDepartment/Shared Documents/Area Class Reference/FIGURE 2.pdf", which I could use as a hyperlink.
Now all I get is "Departments/EIDepartment/Shared Documents/Area Class Reference"
why the change?
I will try and clarify, as recent as last month Dec 2019, when using "export to excel" the Path column in the exported excel file showed the url as ../../ etc and included the file, in this case FIGURE 2.pdf. I could then hyperlink to that and open the file. Now when using export to excel the Path doesn't include the ../ leaders and doesn't include the file name at the end. We are using Sharepoint with our Office 365 software which I am assuming is all the latest version. In my research I can't find any way to find what "version" of Sharepoint one is using.

Comment: Could you detail where exactly you see or used to see that path? In Excel? In what column? What version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, the Path column added to the excel table using Export to Excel feature is used to store the location or sub-folder of the list and the paths are relative URLs.

Comment: If my answer helped you, kindly upvote and Mark it as answer so that it will be helpful to others too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/772e5f21-29a6-4247-938e-7051bea3331b/sharepoint-list-export-to-excel-path-column-incomplete?forum=sharepointgeneral